# Load linux kernel module at boot

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I have written a kernel module for a study research project that is a driver for seven segment displays connected to a Raspberry Pi (I am pretty new to kernel development). I would like to permanently install the module and load it at boot time when it is compiled, so I added the `install` target to my `Makefile` which allows the user to directly compile and install it.

I found out that all kernel modules are located somewhere inside `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel`, so I thought I just had to copy the compiled module into a subdirectory and list the module in the `modules.order` and `modules.dep` files. However, this approach did not work and since I could not find any resources to that topic, I am a little desperate.

This is what my Makefile currently looks like:

```
# All source files are inside the src directory
obj-m := src/sevenseg.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I$(PWD)/src M=$(PWD) modules
    mv src/sevenseg.ko .

install:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I$(PWD)/src M=$(PWD) modules
    mkdir -p /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/sevenseg
    cp src/sevenseg.ko /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/sevenseg
    echo "kernel/drivers/sevenseg/sevenseg.ko:" >> /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/modules.dep
    echo "kernel/drivers/sevenseg/sevenseg.ko" >> /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/modules.order
    insmod src/sevenseg.ko
    make clean

clean:
    rm -rf src
```

How do I tell the kernel that it should load the module `sevenseg.ko` at boot time?

Answer (score 0):

tldr;

```
# echo 'my-module-name' >> /etc/modules
```

Longer explanation:

Consult the documentation on [`insmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/insmod), [`modprobe`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe), and [`modprobe.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.conf).

Here's a decent tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-load-a-kernel-module-automatically-at-boot-time/

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. When I type `modprobe sevenseg` now, I get the same error message as before: `modprobe: FATAL: Module sevenseg not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.59+` and the module is still not being loaded at boot time.

Comment: What is `uname -r` returning? Is it possible you built the module running one kernel, but subsequently booted into another? What is the canonical path to the installed `*.ko` file?